# How to determine whether user is ready and nonce can be submitted to server?

Tags: paypal, braintree

This is one of many (imho rather incomplete) examples in [the docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/setup-and-integration/javascript/v3#client-side-implementation):

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#submit-button');

braintree.dropin.create({
  authorization: 'CLIENT_AUTHORIZATION',
  container: '#dropin-container'
}, function (createErr, instance) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (requestPaymentMethodErr, payload) {
      // Submit payload.nonce to your server
    });
  });
});
```

It's all nice and easy but I don't see how I can change the state of `button` according to the state of "is the user done with adding a payment method?".

Is this even possible? It seems that the click on the button actually performs the fetching of the `nonce` (which comes as `payload.nonce`). However, how can I disable `button` until the user has finished his conversation with Braintree/PayPal?

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is [look in the docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/setup/javascript/v3) (**no not those docs**) - [those docs](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web-drop-in/docs/current/Dropin.html#on).

I still don't know *how* I found that link.

The dropin instance has a `on()` function where you can register a callback for certain events (just do it - look at the docs already):

```js
instance.on('paymentMethodRequestable', function(event) {
  thiz._logger.info('Payment method is now requestable');
  setTimeout(() => thiz.paymentMethodAvailable = true, 400);
});
```